# Where can I find related Google searches for a given search query?

Tags: google-search

I've noticed that Google (and some other search engines, such as Bing) display related search results under a "**People also search for**" heading. Is it possible to view a complete list of related Google searches for a given search query (for example, `google related searches`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) will show related searches and their search-popularity.

Comment: Entering a specific search query will also show searches that are related to that query.

Answer (score 1):

You can view related searches under the "Search Tools" button. By default, the option is set to "All results" instead of "Related searches", but it can easily be changed.